# How to select the result of a match from a dataframe in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to work on selecting row in a dataframe with pandas, but somehow I could not find a similar example of my case. The solution should be simple, but I am stuck a bit.

1. There are two dataframes `kg_df`:

```
    source   edge     target
0   Jack     bought   apple
```

and `mylist`:

```
    Unnamed            URL                        Length     Match Text
0   0           http://example.com/Alice             5        Alice
1   1           http://example.com/Finn              4        Finn
2   2           http://example.com/Jack              4        Jack
```

Above data is just an example (one case). The data in the dataframes are different, each time I generate new data.

2. I want to select a row from `mylist`, using a value from `kg_df` (ie. Jack matches in both dataframes), but I would like to do different operations, if only there are matches between the two dataframes, because sometimes there are no matches (above case has matches, because `Jack` appears in both dataframes).

```
obj = kg_df['source'].values[0]
objhit = mylist[mylist['Match Text'] == obj]
if len(objhit) == 1:
    objURI = objhit ['URL']
    object1 = URIref(objURI[2])
```

So I checking the `len == 1`, but I have trouble to obtain object1. The code above works only because I specify the row number (`objURI[2]`). But, surely I do not know if the result of objhit is found [1] or [99]. How can I get object1 right, without knowing the row number?

Many thanks!

Comment: please add more clarification!

Comment: I think you are checking if the lists are equal instead of checking if they have common elements

Comment: sorry, @Anurag Dhadse, if you do not understand my issue. But I also do not know what you do not understand...so I cannot explain it better unless you specify which part is not understandable. Vasil Yordanov below is confused, but at least gave me an answer to work on.

Comment: @Phineas. Thank you for your comment, but is there a difference of the two? What is it supposed to mean to solve my issue? Any suggestions to refactor my code? Cheers

Comment: When two lists are equal, ALL their elements are the same. I understand that you only need to find the common elements and not if the lists are equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am confused ... why don't you first join both tables to find the common elements and then apply mask however you want ?

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='source', right_on='Match Text', how='inner')
```

Comment: Sorry for confusion. But no problem. This works well. I didnt think of merging. Thanks a lot. I may wait a bit if there are other nice ways to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using dataframe.merge where it will show _merge result as both if result found in both data frames.

```
comparison_df = df.merge(df1, indicator=True, how='outer', left_on='source', right_on='Match Text')
print(comparison_df[(comparison_df['_merge']=='both')].URL)
```

This code will give you URL field from datafram2.

Output:
0    http://example.com/Jack

Comment: Thank you. This works. It is similar to @Vasil Yordanov which comes first.